# Use .sty in IguanaTex

Tags: iguanatex

**How can I use a self written `.sty`-file in IguanaTex?** Where should the file be located?

I have written a long file `MyPersonalStyle.sty` containing all the commands that I frequently use. I use this `.sty`-file` in all of my LaTeX-files. Every time I want to copy LaTeX-code from my papers to IguanaTex-Powepoint I need to redefine all these commands.

I can define a IguanaTex-template

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MyPersonalStyle}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}




\end{document}
```

but where do I need to put `MyPersonalStyle.sty` for IguanaTex to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `.sty` file in the `temp` folder for IguanaTex.